# Worked examples of Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

I'm trying to find the Lie derivative of a 2 form $\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$ with respect to a vector field given in a differential basis and I think the way to go here is to use Cartan's formula but I'm not sure how to do that. I can't find any worked examples in any differential textbook or online, everything seems to focus on proving identities not performing actual calculations. Can somebody point me to a useful resource?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: actually you might be right there

Comment: Which space are you working in? I need to know if $\{d\theta,d\phi\}$ is a basis of one-forms or not.